# Draw vertical line inside Angular2 component using ng2-charts?

Tags: javascript, angular, charts, ng2-charts

I am using latest ng2-charts version `1.4.1` and chart.js `2.4.0`. Can someone tell how can I make a single vertical line using ng2-charts or chart.js

Click http://jsfiddle.net/dbyze2ga/14/

I want to draw line using ng2-charts. How can I access chart.js inside Angular2 component.ts file?

Comment: Also trying to figure out how to add a vertical line in a line graph for a particular day.

Comment: do you find a solution?

Comment: Yes, after lot of POC i came to conclusion that its not possible using angular2-nvd3. So, rightly i shifted to native D3.js